# Removing more than 2 duplicates from a CSV file

Tags: awk

I have found the following script to remove duplicates:

```
awk -F, '!x[$7]++' 'business-records.csv' > 'business-records-deduped.csv'
```

When it finds duplicate records instead of deleting all the duplicates and keeping only the first record it would be amazing if it could keep the first 2 or 3 records and remove the rest. So basically allowing the original and one duplicate but deleting the entire row of any more than one or two duplicates.

How to adjust it so that it keeps the original record and the first duplicate and deletes the entire rows of any more than the first duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `awk` like this:

```bash
awk -F, '++x[$7] <= 2' business-records.csv > business-records-deduped.csv
```

This will keep 2 duplicate records for 7th column and will delete any more dupes as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

I propose following *minimal* ameloration of your code

```
awk -F, '2>x[$7]++' 'business-records.csv' > 'business-records-deduped.csv'
```

Explanation: `++` is *post*-increment operation so execution order might be somewhat counter-intuitive

- `x[$7]` gets value from array `x` for key being content of 7th field, if not present assume 0
- `2>` is test deciding about printing, if this condition does hold line is printed
- `++` does increase value inside array `x`, therefore next time you encounter same 7th field content value will be bigger by 1

Observe that sole thing altered is test, regarding non-negative integers `!` is true for zero and false for values above 0.